# Query parse error: CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula

I try to convert one table to another.

What is wrong with my syntax?

```
=QUERY(B21:D24, "select A,C where A is not null group by A pivot B",1)
```

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

> CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG

means The query cannot use group columns without a `AGG`regate function.

```
select A,C where A is not null group by A pivot B
```

You're asking it to group by A. If the query groups by Column A, What to do with Column C? Column C cannot be displayed side by side. Although your sample doesn't have duplicates in B, think what will happen, if Column B is `a`,`b`,`a`  instead of `a`,`b`,`c`. Column C needs to be aggregated. Said otherwise, For  each group in A, What do you want to do with C(if there are multiple items in C for the same group in A)?

#### Solution:

Provide a Aggregate function for column C like, `sum`, `count`,`max` etc. For each group in A, The corresponding column C will be summed or counted or a max value of C in that group will be taken.

#### Snippet:

```
=QUERY(B21:D24, "select A, sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B",1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following formula to get the `0`'s as well.
It is the `IF` function that will give you the `0`'s in your pivot.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(QUERY(M1:O22, "select M, sum(O) where M is not null group by M pivot N")="",0, 
                 QUERY(M1:O22, "select M, sum(O) where M is not null group by M pivot N")))
```

[image]

As for the syntax, it is [mentioned](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#pivot) that

> If you use a **pivot** clause, then *every column listed* in the **select** clause must either be listed in the group by clause, or be wrapped by an aggregation function

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)